# TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given (django-material)

Tags: python, django, material-design, inline, materialize

I'm trying to recreate a form with Inline using django and django-stuff.
I already got it once but this one is not being easy!

I wish to create a form that can register a Client and its addresses, or something similar to this link here.

Example 1:[Adding contacts](http://demo.viewflow.io/materialforms/pro/hospital/)

Example 2:[Adding addresses](http://demo.viewflow.io/materialforms/pro/signup/#python)

I'm trying like this:

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from material import Layout, Row, Fieldset
from .models import Client


class Address(forms.Form):# TA FEITO
    public_place = forms.CharField(label='Logradouro')
    number = forms.CharField(label='Número')
    city = forms.CharField(label='Cidade')
    state = forms.CharField(label='Estado')
    zipcode = forms.CharField(label='Cep')
    country = forms.CharField(label='País')
    phone = forms.CharField(label='Fone')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'endereços'
        verbose_name = 'endereço'


    def __str__(self):
        return self.profissao


class ClientModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = '__all__'

    layout = Layout(
        Fieldset("Client",
                 Row('name', ),
                 Row('birthday','purchase_limit'),
                 Row('address1', ),
                 Row('compra_sempre', ),
                 ),
    )
```

**Views.py**

```
import extra_views
from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin
from extra_views import CreateWithInlinesView, NamedFormsetsMixin
from material import LayoutMixin, Fieldset
from material.admin.base import Inline

from danibraz.persons.forms import *
from .models import Address


class ItemInline(extra_views.InlineFormSet):
    model = Address
    fields = ['kynd',         'public_place','number','city','state','zipcode','country','phone']#campos do endereço
    extra = 1# Define aquantidade de linhas a apresentar.


class NewClientsView(LoginRequiredMixin,LayoutMixin,
                     NamedFormsetsMixin,
                     CreateWithInlinesView):
    title = "Inclua um cliente"
    model = Client

    #print('Chegou na linha 334')

    layout = Layout(
        Fieldset("Inclua um cliente",
                 Row('name', ),
                 Row('birthday','purchase_limit'),
                 Row('address1', ),
                 Row('compra_sempre', ),
                 ),
        Inline('Endereços', ItemInline),
    )
    #print('Chegou na linha 340')

    def forms_valid(self, form, inlines):
        new = form.save(commit=False)
        new.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return super(NewClientsView, self).forms_valid(form, inlines)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.object.get_absolute_url()
```

**Models.py**

```
# from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Person(models.Model):
    # class Meta:
    #     abstract = True

    name = models.CharField('Nome',max_length=100)
    birthday = models.DateField('Aniversário')
    address1 = models.CharField('Endereço 1',max_length=100)
    purchase_limit = models.DecimalField('Limite de compra',max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'pessoas'
        verbose_name = 'pessoa'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_child(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'client'):
            return self.client
        elif hasattr(self, 'employee'):
            return self.employee
        else:
            return None

def get_type(self):
    if hasattr(self, 'client'):
        return 'client'
    elif hasattr(self, 'employee'):
        return 'employee'
    else:
        return None


class Address(models.Model):
    KINDS_CHOICES = (
        ('P', 'PRINCIPAL'),
        ('C', 'COBRANÇA'),
        ('E', 'ENTREGA'),
    )

person = models.ForeignKey('Person')
kynd = models.CharField('Tipo', max_length=1, choices=KINDS_CHOICES)
public_place = models.CharField('Logradouro',max_length=150)
number = models.CharField('Número',max_length=150)
city = models.CharField('Cidade',max_length=150)
state = models.CharField('Estado',max_length=150)
zipcode = models.CharField('Cep',max_length=10)
country = models.CharField('País',max_length=150, choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES)
phone = models.CharField('Fone',max_length=50)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'endereços'
    verbose_name = 'endereço'

def __str__(self):
    return self.public_place



class Client(Person):
    compra_sempre = models.BooleanField('Compra Sempre',default=False)

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Client, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Cliente'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Clientes'



class Employee(Person):
    ctps = models.CharField('Carteira de Trabalho',max_length=25)
    salary = models.DecimalField('Salário',max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # self.operacao = CONTA_OPERACAO_DEBITO
        super(Employee, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Funcionário'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Funcionários'
```

But djangosempre returns the error below:

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Fix your indentation

Comment: So `Inline()` doesn't take two arguments, it takes just one (plus `self`). Looking at other examples *only the inline form* is expected, so `Inline(ItemInline)`.

Comment: [InLine](https://github.com/viewflow/django-material/blob/master/material/admin/base.py#L16)

Comment: Exactly! However it has the same error but different values from the previous one.

See below:


response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/eliaspai/danibraz/.danibraz/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/eliaspai/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 30, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django Material has no support for the django-extra-views inlines.

With the django-material package, the related object could be handled just like a usual form field.

http://docs.viewflow.io/forms_formsets.html

```
class AddressForm(forms.Form):
    line_1 = forms.CharField(max_length=250)
    line_2 = forms.CharField(max_length=250)
    state = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    zipcode = forms.CharField(max_length=10)

    layout = Layout(
        'line_1',
        'line_2',
        'state',
        Row('city', 'zipcode'),
    )


AddressFormSet = formset_factory(AddressForm, extra=3, can_delete=True)


class SignupForm(Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=250)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=250)
    addresses = FormSetField(formset_class=AddressFormSet)

    layout = Layout(
        'username',
        Row('first_name', 'last_name'),
        'emails',
        Stacked(1, 'addresses'),
    )
```

Comment: Does not work!
Believe that I was able to simulate this in another project, it is working on the other projects I can not replicate in this one.

This is the link that works:
Https://github.com/Elias/sosmypcCoutinho
The url is http://127.0.0.1:8000/site/profissoes/

And this is my project that I can not replicate:
Https://github.com/CoutinhoElias/danibraz

All I want is something similar to the link below:
Http://demo.viewflow.io/materialforms/pro/signup/#python

My frustration is that I got one now but I can not do it now! I do not know what's different!

Comment: The demo you linked is for the PRO version of django-material with additional features, including formsets.

Open source version has no formsets support.

Comment: I understand. But as I mentioned earlier the project [link](Https://github.com/Elias/sosmypcCoutinho) is not using the PRO material and still works.
Would you like to take a look?
The url is as follows
[link](127.0.0.1:8000/site/profissoes)